# Best practice to update large entities in EF Core update

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a table with around 50 columns.

So with EF Core that means every columns is a property.
Now the user have an edit button on the UI to edit around 40 of the 50 properties.
I need to update the entity like this:

```
oldEntity.Property1 = newEntity.Property1;
oldEntity.Property2 = newEntity.Property2;
```

Of course the properties have correct names and sometimes are inhertited etc.

What is the best way to do it without writing all properties down?

Comment: One word: AutoMapper. Or two: AutoMapper or `Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity)`.

Comment: did you try to attach the newEntity ?

Comment: Nit-picky point: there's no such thing as "best practices," just good practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// if greaterThan 4 records then below code will perform bulk update.
public async Task PerfromOperations(IEnumerable<Employees> emps){
    foreach(var emp in emps){
        _dbcontext.Employee.Update(emp);
    }
    _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment of [Ghassen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4112547/ghassen), you can attach the newEntity with the Key of the oldEntity in a new DbContext

```
// entites
SampleObject oldEntity = new SampleObject() { Property1 = "oldEntity", Property2 = "oldEntity2" };
SampleObject newEntity = new SampleObject() { Property1 = "new Value", Property2 = "new Value 2" };

// save oldEntity
using var db = new ApplicationContext();
db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
db.Database.EnsureCreated();
db.Add(oldEntity);
db.SaveChanges();

// retrieve the ID of the oldEntity
var oldEntityId = db.SampleObject.Where(x => x.Property1 == "oldEntity").Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

// use new DbContext(!) and overwrite oldEntity with newEntity
using var db2 = new ApplicationContext();
newEntity.Id = oldEntityId;
db2.Update(newEntity);
db2.SaveChanges();
```

Maybe not elegant, but might be good enough.

Comment: Better to choose first comment and `Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity)` otherwise OP may have exception that entity already tracked. SO is full of such error.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv if you thing about something like
 
```CSharp
db.Add(oldEntity);    
db.SaveChanges();    
db.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity);    
db.SaveChanges();     
```
that's not gonna work out, but results into 
   System.InvalidOperationException : The property 'SampleObject.Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. 

One need to do this modification in a new DbContext, and then it's a one-liner either way.